# MS Access 2013 DSum calculated field DSum returns #error

Tags: ms-access-2013

OK, I have searched for an answer in the usual places, and tried several fixes (i.e. quote syntax, field type) but have still not found a solution to this issue...

I have a calculated field in Access 2013 in a query as follows:

```
CumGPA: DSum([TermGPA],[Transcript_Info],"[Sequence]<=" &[Sequence])
```

Give a running sum of TermGPA for every row from the Transcript_Info table where Sequence is less than or equal to the current row's value

I get the unhelpful #Error returned.

TermGPA and Sequence are Fixed Decimal

Any ideas? I could be staring right at it, but I've been on a long programming binge and can't see straight right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
CumGPA: DSum("TermGPA","Transcript_Info","Sequence<=" &[Sequence])
```